# drawViewHierachyInRect draws iPad at wrong orientation

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, ios7, core-graphics

I’m trying to take a screenshot of my iPad application, and create a `UIImage`, which I can then blur, and do fun stuff with. I’m taking the screenshot with the following code, which is working perfectly:

```
- (UIImage *)convertViewToImage
{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.bounds.size);
    [self drawViewHierarchyInRect:self.bounds afterScreenUpdates:YES];
    UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    return image;
}
```

However, my app supports landscape orientation only, and the screenshot that comes out is rotated 90 degrees to the left (in portrait orientation). I’m calling this method on my `UIWindow`, and I understand that `UIWindow` uses a different coordinate system, but I can’t quite figure out how to rotate that `UIImage`. I’ve read a couple of similar questions here and tried their solution (using `initWithCGImage:scale:orientation`, and re-drawing the image), but since it’s a full-screen iPad image, if I rotate it, it seems to keep the actual portrait dimension, but stretch the rotated image into it.

In a nutshell, the method above is giving me what I need, but at 768x1024, rather than 1024x768. I need to rotate it 90 degrees to the left, exactly the same as rotate would work in Preview, Photoshop, etc.

Comment: Could you call this on the root view controller's view instead?

Comment: I certainly can! Worked perfectly, many thanks. Want to submit an answer so I can mark it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can call it on the root view controller's view instead. That has the same content as the window but with the orientation of the device.